# Keystone js 6: How to add access control on id field of a list

Tags: keystone

I have a problem with adding an access control on an id field of a list, since id field is added automatically when file schema.prisma is added. I want to make an id field with the following access:

```
access: { read: ()=> true, update: ()=> false }
```

I tried to find some explanation in keystone 6 docs, but it seems like there's none. Hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is effectively the only behaviour ID fields support. Specifically:

- You can't restrict read access for ID fields – if a user can read an item, they can always read its ID. The only way to hide the value of item IDs is to use [filter-level access control](https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/access-control#filter) to hide the entire item.
- You can't (easily) update ID values – they're excluded from the GraphQL input types. I don't know if this is explicitly called out in the docs but you can see it in the [examples in the GraphQL overview](https://keystonejs.com/docs/graphql/overview#update-user). This would also be true for the [Query API](https://keystonejs.com/docs/context/query), as it uses the same GraphQL schema under the hood, and I'm pretty sure it's also true for the [DB API](https://keystonejs.com/docs/context/db-items). (If you *did* ever want to modify the value of an ID field, you can *possibly* do it via the [Prisma client](https://keystonejs.com/docs/context/overview#database-access) on `context` – I'm not completely sure.)

For better or worse, these behaviours can't be overridden. ID fields are just special in this respect – they don't support standard field-level access control.